# How to fetch multilevel JSON using volley?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

**My JSON Example where i am willing to get data from every "show" Array**

```
 {
            "score":17.873907,
            "show":{
                "id":139,
                "url":"http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/139/girls",
                "name":"Girls",
                "type":"Scripted",
                "language":"English",
                "genres":[
                    "Drama",
                    "Romance"
                ],
                "status":"Ended",
                "runtime":30,
                "premiered":"2012-04-15",
                "officialSite":"http://www.hbo.com/girls",
                "schedule":{
                    "time":"22:00",
                    "days":[
                        "Sunday"
                    ]
                },
                "rating":{
                    "average":6.7
                },
                "weight":81,
                "network":{
                    "id":8,
                    "name":"HBO",
                    "country":{
                        "name":"United States",
                        "code":"US",
                        "timezone":"America/New_York"
                    }
                },
                "webChannel":null,
                "externals":{
                    "tvrage":30124,
                    "thetvdb":220411,
                    "imdb":"tt1723816"
                },
                "image":{
                    "medium":"http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/31/78286.jpg",
                    "original":"http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/31/78286.jpg"
                },
                "summary":"<p>This Emmy winning series is a comic look at the assorted humiliations and rare triumphs of a group of girls in their 20s.</p>",
                "updated":1600633829,
                "_links":{
                    "self":{
                        "href":"http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/139"
                    },
                    "previousepisode":{
                        "href":"http://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/1079686"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**The Request Code I am using which is giving me the response nicely but i cannot parse the response to JSONObject**

[image]

**Error Showing**

> org.json.JSONException: Value show of type java.lang.String cannot be
> converted to JSONObject

Comment: what is new JSONObject("show")??

Comment: it should be something like new JSONObject(response)

Comment: JSONObject(response) also show exception on type can not be converted to JSON object.

Comment: can you log response before converting it to jsonobj.? make sure you are getting a json string

Comment: please, provide you code as text, not as picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution Was **"I Used Nested Model Class to Load Data, and that worked like a charm!"**

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing JSONObject("show") , it is trying to convert 'show' string to json Obviously it isn't json stirng so it is throwing error;
It should be something like :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject obj_show= obj.getJSONObject("show"));
Log.d("show",obj_show.getJSONObject("show").toString());
```

Comment: Still Gives Value Exception